# Java reading csv and understanding types

Tags: java, floating-point

I need to read from a csv file.  The file has some different types like `int`, `float`, `String`, `char`.  How can I know what the type is?

I did write some code for it but my problem is with floating point numbers.  In my computer java say that "7.9" is not a floating point number, but "7,9" is.

But on some computers "7.9" is a float.  How can I solve this?

```
public static void Read(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file);
    String line ;
    Scanner scanner;
    int a;
    float f;
    String temp ;
    while(scanner1.hasNextLine()){
        line = scanner1.nextLine();
        scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
        while (scanner.hasNext()){

            if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
                a = scanner.nextInt();
                System.err.printf("Int :%d",a);
            }
            else if(scanner.hasNextFloat()){
                f = scanner.nextFloat();
                System.err.printf("flt :%f",f);

            }
            else {
                temp = scanner.next();
                if(temp.length() == 1)
                    System.err.printf("char:%s",temp);
                else
                    System.err.printf("string:%s",temp);
            }
        }
        System.err.printf("\n");

        scanner.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Note: This won't properly read in CSV files with strings which contain commas.  Ie) `1,2,3,"A,B,C"` contains 4 values, the last being a string with 2 commas.  You should use a proper CSV library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more I read this more I realize I was wrong.

If your CSV data is like

1,2,3,4

Then it could be (1,2 and 3,4) eg (1.2, 3.4) or it could be the integers 1 through 4

If its properly quoted
"1,2","3,4"

Then your parser wont work because its not using quotes as the delimiters.

So its hard to say what is causeing your issue with out seeing the data.
You could add handeling of the quotes in your scanner but there are more cases inolved if your vlaues contain quotes themselves

Ideally use a proper CSV parse like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Otherwise you need to walk through your data nad make sure your parse is covering all the cases you have today, and might have tomorrow.

A hack work around would be to modify your strings using replaceAll(".",","); but there are many pitfulls when doing that again, your scanner may confuse the elements as new entries in your CSV.

Specifically to change from representing decimals from 1,2 to 1.2 you can modify the Local for the number types you want with

```
scanner1.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

From what I can tell there is no way to have more than one locale for the scanner. One approach is to use two scanners, with two different Locales at the same time to parse the float differently.

Comment: Replacing "." with "," won't work at the indicated point.  The CSV line contains _**Comma** Separated Values_; so instead of 4 floating point values, you'd convert the line to appear to contain 8 integers.

Comment: Good point, so you would have to do this
 line = scanner1.nextLine().replaceAll(",",";");
 line = scanner1.nextLine().replaceAll(".",",");
 scanner.useDelimiter(";|\\n");

Again depending on the data

Comment: Close, but not quite.  You read in a line, converted commas to semi-colons, and then discarded it, read in the next line, and converted periods to commas.  You wanted `line = scanner1.nextLine().replaceAll(",",";").replaceAll(".",",");`  Again, still the wrong approach; changing the scanner's locale is best.

Comment: I agree Locale is the most correct, Except he wants to support both forms at the same time. Which locale doesnt allow.

Comment: Probably more efficient to run two Scanners with different Locales

Comment: I see here about nothing about supporting multiple locales; just reading a Comma-Separated-Value file, where fields are always separated by commas, and floating point numbers always use `.` as the decimal point.  Only a single scanner, with an appropriate locale, is required.  Changing the locale of the scanner does not change the locale for the rest of the program, so nine-and-a-half will still be represented as `9,5` elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138970/discussion-between-ajneufeld-and-jim).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scanner's locale using [#useLocale(java.util.Locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale))

Set the locale to one which uses `.` as the decimal point.  I.e)

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");   
scanner.useLocale( Locale.US );    // Use '.' as decimal point
```